# Ошибка при компиляции исходников java

Tags: java, консоль

Здравствуйте, только начал изучать java. У меня три класса взятые из учебника:

Класс запуска программы:

```
public class GameLauncher{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     GuessGame game = new GuessGame();
     game.startGame();
   }
}
```

И 2 класса где непосредственно происходят операции:

```
 public class GuessGame{

   Player p1;
   Player p2;
   Player p3;

   public void startGame(){
       p1 = new Player();
       p2 = new Player();
       p3 = new Player();
  ............................  
  ............................
   }
  }
```

Третий класс:

```
public class Player{
    int number = 0;
    public void guess(){
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("ƒумаю это число " + number);
    }
}
```

При компиляции GameLauncher.java и GuessGame.java через командную строку выходят ошибки: 
ошибка GameLauncher.java
[image: ошибка GameLauncher.java]

ошибка GuessGame.java
[image: ошибка GuessGame.java]

Player.java компилируется без ошибок. Также никаких проблем нет при компиляции
в IDE IntelliJ IDEA. Подскажите как исправить проблему в консоли.

Comment: Импорты все есть?

Comment: Дык как правильно импорты вписать не знаю. Пробовал импортировать содержимое папки "5" (где находятся все java-файлы): "import 5;", "import 5.*;", но компилятор ругался уже на импорты.

Comment: Повторюсь, что в IDE IntelliJ IDEA ни каких проблем нет, хотя там ни импортов, ни пакетов не указывал. В общем с консолью у меня пока беда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перейдите в директорию с вашими java файлами и запускайте компиляцию в ней.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, не ожидал, что всё так легко и просто))